# MS Access query: Mutliple source tables for one particular field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to write a query in MS access. I need to populate data for a particular field from two different tables based on a criteria. (Ex: Pick data from table X if State is Kerala else pick data from table Y). I have multiple tables linked based on a primary key. I am using 'Make Table' query option in MS access to get the desired output in form of a table, need to incorporate a a query for picking data from multiple sources in the same. Is it possible. Can some conditions be given? Kindly let me know.

Tables:
[The image has tables, I need a query such that when the state is KL the data has to be picked from table 3 else from table 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3gjH.png)

Comment: if only one column  use   iif(field='Kerala', dlookup(),dlookup())  in query

Comment: I have 3 such columns, is there a way to use dlookup for three columns?

Comment: it is possible, if you give your table structure i could give better solution

Comment: Added it in a image format with my question.

Comment: since your conc column got link with each other you could easily join them by select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.conc=table2.conc inner join table3 on table1.conc=table3.conc and pick the desired colum from the query designer

Comment: and your complete query look like - select * , iif(table1.state="KK",Table2.column,table3.column) as result from (table1 inner join table2 on table1.conc=table2.conc) inner join table3 on table1.conc=table3.conc

Comment: What I want to do is update one single column with two different columns.
I want a third column in Table 1 with values from Table 2, evening and Table 3, Tentative (Only when State=KL).
So When Conc is 45, the third column in Table 1 should display 90000 where as for other values of Conc the values should be picked from Table2, evening column.

Comment: posted the answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write procedure for that follow MSDN [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you could make an IF statement to check your conditions and then have it execute two different sql statements based on your test.

```
IF [State] = "Kerala" Then
  Docmd.RunSQL "SELECT x, y, z INTO TEMP_Table FROM Table X"
ELSE:
  DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT x, y, z INTO TEMP_Table FROM Table Y"
End IF
```

If your Temp_table needs data from multiple tables regardless of the condition, use subqueries in your statement to join your tables together before running `SELECT ... INTO`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am unable to get the output. Not sure if I am doing it right.
The data from two different tables needs to be populated in one single field. I am entering the IF statements in query SQL view.